# Using DBMS_RANDOM.Value function in SQL query for equality comparison - returning multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle, random, oracle11g

I am on Oracle 11g and the case is as follows.

I have a select from subquery, like this:

```
    select * from (
        select rownum as rn
        , 'just testing_' || rownum as just_string 
        from dual
        connect by level <= 20
    ) 
    where rn = round(dbms_random.value(1,20))
```

so the result of subquery is 20 records with numeric column "rn" value from 1 to 20, and I expect to get one record from that subquery by comparing to result of DBMS_RANDOM.value, which I expect to get me an integer value from 1 to 20

However... result os such query tend to vary from no records to multiple records:
[image]
[image]

If I enclose the DBMS_RANDOM.value function in subquery like this:

```
select * from (
    select rownum as rn
    , 'just testing_' || rownum as just_string 
    from dual
    connect by level <= 20
) 
where rn = (select round(dbms_random.value(1,20)) from dual)
```

then it seems to always return one row as expected.

**So can anyone explain how the first query works with DBMS_RANDOM.value so that it returns multiple or no rows ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbms_random.value gets executed for each row that is returned by your subquery, not just one time. So your first query  may return any number of rows between 0 and 20 (last one very, very, ... unlikely). The second query executes dbms_random.value just once, as dual has 1 row, and so it always returns just one row.

Comment: Thanks, somehow forgot that function will get executed for each row :)